# Tomcat6 Refuses To Start In Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I get the following error when trying to start eclipse on my Windows XP machine at home inside of Eclipse, I can start it using "catalina.bat start" from a clean command line without any issues.

Being as they're socket errors I'm completely confused, Firewall is off, even tried using "Run As" on eclipse and turning off system protection.

```
Aug 21, 2011 2:21:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;.

Aug 21, 2011 2:21:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin

WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:NOC' did not find a matching property.

Aug 21, 2011 2:21:57 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init

SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint

java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:264)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:214)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:524)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:548)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)

Aug 21, 2011 2:21:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load

SEVERE: Catalina.start

LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:524)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:548)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)

Aug 21, 2011 2:21:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load

INFO: Initialization processed in 495 ms

Aug 21, 2011 2:21:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start

INFO: Starting service Catalina

Aug 21, 2011 2:21:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26

Aug 21, 2011 2:21:58 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start

SEVERE: Error starting endpoint

java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:264)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:214)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:150)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.start(JIoEndpoint.java:565)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.start(Http11Protocol.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Aug 21, 2011 2:21:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

SEVERE: Catalina.start: 

LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1094)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Aug 21, 2011 2:21:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

INFO: Server startup in 354 ms

Aug 21, 2011 2:21:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await

SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8005]: 

java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:264)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:214)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:373)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:662)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: seems like you're not the first to encounter this. I googled "Unrecognized Windows Sockets" and got this: http://www.coderanch.com/t/207423/sockets/java/java-net-SocketException-Unrecognized-Windows

Comment: Hah, I thought that was completely irrelevant being as I'm running XP Pro and it runs fine at the command prompt. In Eclipse I explicitly defined SYSTEMROOT and it worked, post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you answered yourself, explicitly define SYSTEMROOT in Eclipse and it works.

Comment: where in eclipse? And where should it point to? To JRE? If it in the settings for Tomcat? @Eran

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I last used Eclipse, and I don't really remember.. Maybe @StrangeWill remembers?