# Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create when starting tomcat in the command line

Tags: windows, sockets, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm starting a newly extracted tomcat in the command line on windows 10. I'm using java 8

```
startup.bat
```

Since tomcat is not starting I ran:

```
catalina.bat run
```

Here's the full stack trace:

```
    INFO: Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.69
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built: Apr 11 2016 07:57:09 UTC
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server number: 7.0.69.0
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name: Windows 10
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version: 10.0
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture: amd64
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version: 1.8.0_91-b14
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor: Oracle Corporation
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE: C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME: C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -D java.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\conf\logging.properties
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -D java.util.logging.manager=  org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -D java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\endorsed
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -D java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\temp
    Jun 06, 2016 11:44:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the   java.library.path: C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\DevSuiteHome\jdk\jre\bin\classic;C:\DevSuiteHome\jdk\jre\bin;C:\DevSuiteHome\jdk\jre\bin\client;C:\DevSuiteHome\jlib;C:\DevSuiteHome\bin;C:\DevSuiteHome\jre\1.4.2\bin\client;C:\DevSuiteHome\jre\1.4.2\bin;C:\Program
Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program
Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program
Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\bin;.
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
        SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:307)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:650)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:560)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:838)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:642)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:667)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:427)

    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
    SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:560)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:838)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:642)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:667)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:427)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:307)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:650)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    ... 13 more

    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:307)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:650)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:560)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:838)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:642)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:667)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:427)

    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
    SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:560)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:838)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:642)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:667)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:427)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:307)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:650)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    ... 13 more

    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 2083 ms
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.69
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\docs
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\docs has finished in 595 ms
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\examples
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\examples has finished in 1,403
ms
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\host-manager
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\host-manager has finished in
84 ms
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\manager
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\manager has finished in 81
ms
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\ROOT
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\Rene\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\ROOT has finished in 55 ms
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 2308 ms
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
    SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]:
    java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:307)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:781)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:727)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)

    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFO: Stopping service Catalina
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
    INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
    INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Jun 06, 2016 11:45:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

What is this? How can I fix this? I am sure no one is using the ports 8005, 8009 and 8080. What should I do?

Comment: I'd start scanning your machine for malware.

Comment: @BalusC what do you mean?

Comment: WinSock error 10106 is `WSAEPROVIDERFAILEDINIT`: "*Service provider failed to initialize. The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized. This error is returned if either a service provider's DLL could not be loaded (LoadLibrary failed) or the provider's WSPStartup or NSPStartup function failed.*"

Comment: Possibly related: [Tomcat6 Refuses To Start In Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140197/) and [Minecraft Launcher Java Error- java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163543/)

Comment: @BalusC can you explain more? How is malware related to this error?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau all I did is extract the tomcat zip, then created the CATALINA_HOME variable. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @morbidCode I can't answer that, I don't use tomcat. Whatever tomcat is doing to initialize Winsock is failing.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau is there anything more I can do to find the problem? I tried the netstat command but 8080 is not there. BTW, when I run tomcat in eclipse it says "several ports ... in use".